# How to exit a 'git status' list in a terminal?

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

How can I exit a terminal listing mode generated by the `git status` command?

Answer (score 614):

I have to guess here, but git is probably running its output into your $PAGER program, likely `less` or `more`. In either case, typing <kbd>q</kbd> should get you out.

Comment: The pager used by git is selected by  `core.pager` configuration variable (if it is set), then GIT\_PAGER enviroment variable, then PAGER environment variable, then `less` as fallback.

Comment: Typing `q` also helps in exiting list mode generated by the `git diff` command. ThumbsUp

Comment: `git config --global core.pager "less -F -X"` made it behave the way I wanted - no pager for status, branch, etc, but page things like git log

Answer (score 214):

```
:q
```

that's a [less](https://web.archive.org/web/20091126114320/http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less) command, actually. It uses the same commands as [vi](https://web.archive.org/web/20091211193500/http://www.uic.edu/depts/accc/software/unixgeneral/vi101.html).

Comment: If it's less, then no colon (:) is needed. You're thinking if vi!

Comment: If you're getting the **E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)** error, do what it says and use `:q!`

Comment: `:q` was what as needed for me even though the terminal was inside less.exe just q did nothing. Thanks @RageZ

Answer (score 139):

Type 'q' and it will do the job.

Whenever you are at the terminal and have a similar predicament keep in mind also to try and type 'quit', 'exit' as well as the abort key combination 'Ctrl + C'.

Comment: I was using 'Ctrl + Z' and ended up with a ton of unterminated git processes when I ran ```ps -ax```. Did not know about ```q```.

Comment: Ctrl+Z puts tasks in the background, so that makes sense. I personally couldn't get Ctrl+C to close it. q works.

Comment: Ctrl+C and Ctrl+X neither worked, only `:q` was able to get out for me.

Comment: I typed yes to a question which did ask for me to type yes or no. I pressed `q`, `esc` and many other keys and none of them worked until I can across `CTRL + C` and it got me out of it!

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> will do the trick. This will get you out of many extensive page scrolling sessions like `git status`, `git show HEAD`, `git diff` etc. This will not exit your window or end your session.

Answer (score 17):

for windows :

Ctrl + q and c for exit the running situation .

Answer (score 11):

My preferred combo is `Gq`, which prints all diffs and then exits.

You can type `h` to show the help commands for interacting with less, which prints this to console:

```
                   SUMMARY OF LESS COMMANDS

      Commands marked with * may be preceded by a number, N.
      Notes in parentheses indicate the behavior if N is given.

  h  H                 Display this help.
  q  :q  Q  :Q  ZZ     Exit.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           MOVING

  e  ^E  j  ^N  CR  *  Forward  one line   (or N lines).
  y  ^Y  k  ^K  ^P  *  Backward one line   (or N lines).
  f  ^F  ^V  SPACE  *  Forward  one window (or N lines).
  b  ^B  ESC-v      *  Backward one window (or N lines).
  z                 *  Forward  one window (and set window to N).
  w                 *  Backward one window (and set window to N).
  ESC-SPACE         *  Forward  one window, but don't stop at end-of-file.
  d  ^D             *  Forward  one half-window (and set half-window to N).
  u  ^U             *  Backward one half-window (and set half-window to N).
  ESC-)  RightArrow *  Left  one half screen width (or N positions).
  ESC-(  LeftArrow  *  Right one half screen width (or N positions).
  F                    Forward forever; like "tail -f".
  r  ^R  ^L            Repaint screen.
  R                    Repaint screen, discarding buffered input.
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Default "window" is the screen height.
        Default "half-window" is half of the screen height.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                          SEARCHING

  /pattern          *  Search forward for (N-th) matching line.
  ?pattern          *  Search backward for (N-th) matching line.
  n                 *  Repeat previous search (for N-th occurrence).
  N                 *  Repeat previous search in reverse direction.
  ESC-n             *  Repeat previous search, spanning files.
  ESC-N             *  Repeat previous search, reverse dir. & spanning files.
  ESC-u                Undo (toggle) search highlighting.
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Search patterns may be modified by one or more of:
        ^N or !  Search for NON-matching lines.
        ^E or *  Search multiple files (pass thru END OF FILE).
        ^F or @  Start search at FIRST file (for /) or last file (for ?).
        ^K       Highlight matches, but don't move (KEEP position).
        ^R       Don't use REGULAR EXPRESSIONS.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           JUMPING

  g  <  ESC-<       *  Go to first line in file (or line N).
  G  >  ESC->       *  Go to last line in file (or line N).
  p  %              *  Go to beginning of file (or N percent into file).
  t                 *  Go to the (N-th) next tag.
  T                 *  Go to the (N-th) previous tag.
  {  (  [           *  Find close bracket } ) ].
  }  )  ]           *  Find open bracket { ( [.
  ESC-^F <c1> <c2>  *  Find close bracket <c2>.
  ESC-^B <c1> <c2>  *  Find open bracket <c1> 
        ---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9):

You can disable pager for commands that don't recognize `--no-pager` flag.

```
git config --global pager.<command> false
```

I disable for log aliases and set specific quantity to return.

```
git config --global pager.log false
```

Answer (score 8):

In Linux Terminal

After  `git diff`   typing

```
 :q
```

you can exit from screen showing changes accross pages.

After you performed merge your project from remote or pull updates from remote

```
ctrl + x
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try this steps in git bash, It may help you.

1. `CTRL + C`
2. `:qa!`

Answer (score 5):

first of all you need to setup line ending preferences in termnial

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
git config --global core.safecrlf true
```

Then you can use `:q`

Comment: One note for Windows users: For me, adding these lines resulted in the inability to add files to tracking (fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in README.md). So if you're using Windows, please add `git config --global core.autocrlf true` instead, it will do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Before pressing exit commands(q, etc..) check current input language: if it isn't English commands may not work.

Answer (score 3):

Crt + c works for Windows! user1852392

Answer (score 3):

## If you are facing this?

[image]
Sometimes it is possible that while writing in Gitbash you get into > and you just can not get out of that.
It happens with me quite often while I type ' by mistake in Gitbash(See in the image).

### How to solve this in Mac?

> control + C

I have not checked it in Windows. But if it does please edit that in my answer.

Comment: I have checked it working for windows as well ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the git bash try using exit;

I tried using the q or ctrl + q but they did not worked on bash.

Answer (score 0):

[try this and see the image too]

I tried other methods but didnt work. I just put 'cd ../'
and it worked

codes:

> > zsh: command not found: Q

$(virtual) ➜  ML git:(master) quit

> > zsh: command not found: quit

$(virtual) ➜  ML git:(master) quit()

> > function>

$(virtual) ➜  ML git:(master) cd ../

> > (virtual) ➜  final

Answer (score 0):

> You can press the 'q' key on your keyboard. This command stands for
> "quit" and will close the list, returning you to the command prompt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to StackOverflow! Please avoid posting answers that are duplicates of already existing ones for the same question. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

`exit` did it for me.
My results after pressing return;

```
my-mac:Car Game mymac$ exit
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
    ...completed.
[Process completed]
```

Comment: this is same as closing the whole window, question asks to exit from git session like in ssh