# How do I exit the results of 'git diff' in Git Bash on windows?

Tags: git, diff, msysgit

I'm using [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) on Windows 7. When I run `git diff`, I see this:

[image]

However, I'm unable to get back to a regular prompt. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to work, but as soon as I start typing a command, it's covered up with `(END)` as in that image.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696433/how-to-exit-a-git-status-list-in-terminal

Answer (score 1194, accepted):

I think pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> should work.

Comment: By the way, it works not only for Windows.

Comment: Too bad they can't like -- add other key combinations that are more intuitive to users (like Escape and Ctrl+C) -- or gods forbid, just let it exit normally (and if the user really needs paging, let them pipe it through "less" or "more", etc.).

Comment: This worked as expected in Windows 8.1's powershell v4.0, although it took a few seconds to complete.

Comment: worked with ESC then Q in windows 7. Thanks

Comment: Using Webstorm in Mac and Q works too

Comment: Warning - this closes the console that launched `git diff` not just the git session.

Comment: Sigh. Why can't it just say `(END - Press Q to exit)`??

Comment: This also closes the window for me.

Comment: this close the whole window. why not just write ALT+F4

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 they keep it in the tradition of linux text editors - as obscure as possible

Comment: indeed, on windows... this should be stated clearly by git bash .

Comment: nice. ESC not worked for me. Also ctrlc+c not working. But "Q" worked.

Answer (score 64):

None of the above solutions worked for me on **Windows 8**

But the following command works fine

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: Both Q and Shift+Q worked for me on Windows 8.

Comment: SHIFT + Q in MAC Too.

Comment: Does not work for me. I am using `cmd` though...

Comment: This worked for me in Github's Git Shell (poshgit?) on Windows Server 2012 Standard

Comment: SHIFT-Q worked for me in powershell 3.0 on win7. Q would exit powershell

Answer (score 41):

Using <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> worked for me. Just <kbd>q</kbd> alone gave me "command not found" and eventually it jumped back into the git diff insanity.

Comment: EXACTLY my problem. I know how to use less, but whatever ships with git on Windows doesn't respond to less commands. ":q", ":z," any other command entered is piped to the command line, instead of interpreted.

Comment: This was the solution on Win7 + Cmder as well.

Comment: This just brings up my windows search bar. No luck with any answers (I'm using conda within windows powershell)