# How to stop/cancel 'git log' command in terminal?

Tags: terminal, command

In terminal, I ran this command `git log` . It displayed a list of log but it seems that because it is long, the terminal is not displaying everything. Below logs there is  `:` that I can see more logs when I hit enter key.

How do I terminate a command, and show the prompt for running another one.

Based on my search, I realized that `ctrl+c` should be used, but it doesn't work for me. I tried to enter `!` and it stopped that task and I returned to `$`. But I'm not sure this is correct way because when hit `!`, from ./a/b/c moved me to ./a/b/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can hit the key <kbd>q</kbd> (for *quit*) and it should take you to the prompt.

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696433/how-to-exit-a-git-status-list-in-terminal).

Comment: Also, just for future reference.  You can hit h (for help) and it will give you the whole list of commands--very much acts how the man pages do.

Comment: I never expect this question to be here, but yeah many people are stuck after running commad `git log -10`